# Spring Data JPA - Specification Hibernate Spatial

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, geospatial

I am developing a spring boot app that stores Geometry data. I use Specification to query with Spring Data. Springboot 3 and hibernate 6.2.2

Below is my code which results in an error:

> Passed `invariantType` for function return cannot be null

Code:

```
Expression<Geometry> geography = cb.function("geography", Geometry.class, root.get("point"));
Expression<Point> point = cb.function("point", Point.class, cb.literal(longitude),
cb.literal(latitude));
Expression<Point> comparisonPoint = cb.function("ST_SetSRID", Point.class, point,
cb.literal(4326));
Expression<Boolean> expression = cb.function(SpatialFunction.dwithin.toString(), boolean.class,
geography, comparisonPoint, cb.literal(radius));

return cb.equal(expression, true);
```

Comment: Any assistant will be highly appreciated thanx